# The expectation of the product of an estimator with its transpose

Tags: matrices, statistics, expected-value, economics, linear-regression

I hope you are well. I have a problem that it seems to be really easy but I just don't know how to find the solution.
So, this is the question ; I have to compute **E(Ŷ'Ŷ)**. For that, I have some informations to use (I will show some formulas and the β is an estimator, I just don't know how to put an accent on it, sorry...) :

1. Ŷ = X β
2. β = ((X ′ X)^(-1)) X ′ Y
3. the properties of the trace : tr(ab) = tr(ba)

And I have to find something with E(Ŷ'Ŷ), a solution but I just don't know what ... can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I will denote the estimator by $\hat\beta$. Under the model $Y=X\beta+\epsilon$ with $E[X'\epsilon]=0,$ we have

$$\begin{align}E[\hat Y'\hat Y]&=E[(X\hat \beta)'X\hat \beta]\\
&=E[\hat \beta'X'X\hat \beta]\\
&=E[Y'X(X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y]\\
&=E[Y'X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y]\\
&=E[(X\beta+\epsilon)'X(X'X)^{-1}X'(X\beta+\epsilon)]\\
&=E[\beta'X'X\beta+2\epsilon'X\beta+\epsilon'X(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon]\\
&=\beta'E[X'X]\beta+E[\epsilon'X(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon].\\
\end{align}$$

From here, appeal to any further model assumptions you have.